# Php need help Blob Data Read

Tags: php

```
$test =$db->getrows("SELECT * FROM trnskriptfolder");
 $blob_data = fbsql_read_blob($test[0]['tfolder']);
 echo $blob_data;
```

//Call to undefined function  here`fbsql_read_blob()

Comment: what is your php version

Comment: You can check (01) requirement link: http://php.net/manual/en/fbsql.requirements.php , (02) installation link: http://php.net/manual/en/fbsql.installation.php , (03) function reference link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fbsql-read-blob.php which shows example of how to read data.